# Why would change with "sed" via Putty not reflect in Cpanel?

Tags: linux, sed, cpanel

I did a word replace with "sed" via Putty and i see that the word was replaced but when I open the file in cpanel there is no change to the file.

Here's the command

```
sed 's/word1/word2/g' file.php
```

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/word1/word2/g' file.php
```

prints out the changed version of the file. If you want to modify the file in-place, use the `-i` option:

```
sed 's/word1/word2/g' -i file.php
```